# Chrome 37 UI got larger and became blurry on 125% DPI

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1

Today I updated to **Chrome 37** stable (64-bit, but 32-bit has the same issue).

I am using **125% DPI mode** in Windows 8.1, because I need larger fonts everywhere, since my eyes are not so good :)

The problem is that, after updating, the size of Chrome's interface has notably increased and both the interface and the fonts started to look **blurry** and horrible.

I tried the following things and none of them worked:

1. Disabling ***DirectWrite*** in `chrome://flags`. Weirdly, not just that this does not work, but the font kerning (distance between letters) gets uneven.
2. Enabling ***distance field text***.
3. Enabling the compatiblity option ***Disable display scaling on high DPI settings***.
4. Enabling the **high DPI mode** on Chrome by following [this article](http://www.ubergizmo.com/how-to/how-to-google-chrome-hidpi-support-windows/).
5. In the control panel, clicking on ***Make text and other items larger or smaller*** and toggling the option ***Let me choose one level for all my displays***.
6. Changing Chrome settings ***default page zoom*** and ***default font size***.

Is there a solution to this problem which doesn't involve changing my Windows DPI to 100% or going back to Chrome 36?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Right click the shortcut icon, and add the following to the Target field under the Shortcut tab: `/high-dpi-support=1 /force-device-scale-factor=1`

So it looks like:

```
.../chrome.exe" /high-dpi-support=1 /force-device-scale-factor=1
```

Close out of Chrome and launch it using the updated shortcut. It should be back to normal. (You may need to delete and re-pin the icon to your taskbar for the change to take effect there as well.)

Comment: This worked for me perfectly, both the UI and the fonts issue are gone. Thank you very much!

Comment: If this doesn't work, be sure to close all running chrome processes from the taskbar before re-running the shortcut with the flags

Comment: Update: I use a few Chrome background apps. Because of that, Chrome always has a running background task. Now, every time I turn my computer on, this task runs automatically at startup and then when I open Chrome, it still has the original issue, even though the flags are in place in the shortcut target. I figured out that I have to exit Chrome from the taskbar icon (to turn off the background service) and then to re-run Chrome. Now I do it on every Windows startup. It's not so big of a deal, but maybe someone knows a solution to this.

Comment: As the question is protected by a community and I cannot leave the answer... Here it goes.

First of all - the --high-dpi-support flag is going away. Now you have to use the registry. Which is actually good, as the registry values should apply to ALL running chrome processes, including background ones. You should change flag high-dpi=support in  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\Profile] to 1 (always enabled) and restart. This should last. If not - change second option (force-device-scale-factor) in chrome://flags (enter chrome://flags as URL, find this option, change to 1, restart).

Comment: @TomaszStruczyński: the key is `high-dpi-support` (small typo there) and it should be a DWORD type, according to http://goo.gl/BU3nCN. Also, as of Chrome 38, you cannot set `force-device-scale-factor` to anything lower than 1.1 from the `chrome://flags` page -- setting it to 1 via the shortcut still seems to work, but that doesn't work for background processes. Also, I had to create the key `Profile` under `Chrome` myself. Furthermore, I should note, that none of the above worked for me in the end.

Comment: Just for the record, I had the same issue as the topic starter, but on Linux and I got fixed it by adding the options suggested in this answer! Thank you, Jason!