# Text in Google Chrome looks jagged

Tags: google-chrome

I am having some trouble with my Chrome Browser, rendered text looks really messy.

*Screenshot of text in Chrome:*

[image]

---

*The same website and piece of text, rendered in Firefox:*

[image]

I have found a similar issue here:
[Chrome's fonts look off](https://superuser.com/questions/821092/chromes-fonts-look-off)

I have tried all the posted suggestions, (plus resetting it to default and a complete re-install) but none of them worked, my Chrome is also up-to-date.

Edit:

The behavior seems to be triggered by the "Helvetica Neue" font family, I have verified this now on several websites. If I remove the "Helvetica Neue" reference from the CSS via the Developer console, the text is rendering just fine?

Comment: I would follow this [Quora Post](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-fix-the-Helvetica-Neue-Chrome-browser-problem-without-deleting-the-font) like you said it is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this in Windows 10 by going Control Panel -> search for "Adjust the appearance and performance of Windows" and ensure "Smooth edges of screen fonts" is checked.[image]