# Chrome is not showing fonts properly

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

This only happens to a YouTube and Google as far as I'm aware.

[image: Google Search]

[image: YouTube]

---

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? Could it be that it's my graphics card, but then again as I said this only happens to these specific websites. Other websites such as SuperUser it's perfectly fine.

---

EXTRA: Turns out it's due to the Roboto font. At least that's what I think. I inspected all the suspected sites and they're all using 'Roboto' fonts. So, any ideas?

Comment: The dead simplest solution is reinstall chrome and maybe the font, but if that fails or is not favorable there are [many](https://superuser.com/questions/821092/chromes-fonts-look-off) alternate [solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37301132/chrome-overall-font-rendering-issue-2016).

Comment: @Kevin I have definitely tried reinstalling. That did not work, so I'll check out those two alternates you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Kevin. It was apparently Adobe Creative Clouds that was messing with the fonts. I have uninstalled it and Chrome works perfectly fine now.

You can also just go to "Elements", "Fonts" and disable all synced fonts. -Johannes Bluhm. And that will fix the issue as well. Though I just decided to uninstall it.

Answer (score -1):

YMMV... Been struggling w/ Chrome gmail font colors for about 6 months.  I finally opened up Font Book on my mac and clicked on Restore Standard Fonts in the file menu.  Now I can see unread emails in Chrome/Gmail again!