# Disable Chrome DPI scaling from link, not shortcut

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, dpi

I'm using Windows 7 64-bit with 125% DPI mode.

With the new Chrome release (stable channel) 38.0.2125.101, the Chrome window blows up in size. I've tried [this fix](https://superuser.com/questions/803601/text-size-suddenly-got-bigger-on-all-sites-on-google-chrome/803650#803650), which works when I launch Chrome from the shortcut / taskbar tile. However, when Chrome is not already open and I click a link from another application (e.g. Outlook), it opens Chrome without the disabled DPI scaling. How can I make this fix work whether I open Chrome via a shortcut or through some other means (like clicking a link when Chrome is my default browser)?

[Screenshot of Chrome opened from shortcut with `/high-dpi-support=1 /force-device-scale-factor=1` flags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3j0r.png)

[Screenshot of Chrome opened by clicking link from external application, invoking default browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qQmi.png) (this is the same behavior observed without the flags)

**edit: the issue seems to have been fixed by Chromium developers with release 38.0.2125.104**

Comment: @imtheman Read that post, but it doesn't seem to have the answer. The accepted answer points to a Chrome bug report; the fix for that bug was added in v37, I'm using v38 already. Also, changing the zoom of the text in the pages doesn't help, it's the entire Window (including buttons, omnibox, etc.) that are oversized.

Comment: See [this](http://superuser.com/a/803796/337631) answer, in particular the last comment about changing these values in the registry not the shortcut, then restarting.

Comment: @DavidPostill: thanks, I tried going down the registry route, but to no avail. By the way, his comment had some problems, I made corrections [here](http://superuser.com/questions/803710/chrome-37-ui-got-larger-and-became-blurry-on-125-dpi/803796#comment1083277_803796). I may have to just wait for Google to fix this one.

Comment: The issue seems to be fixed with the newest Chrome version: 38.0.2125.104