# Choppy font rendering on Windows Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1, fonts, resolution

So this was supposed to be fixed with Directwrite in Chrome 37, but unfortunately I think I am one of a very few people, if not the only one who it actually backfired on. My fonts were perfectly fine for months up until a few days ago when I believe I must have received the update.

The first time I had this problem, my solution, which worked even though it was strange was to delete the google fonts from my computer (they were installed so I could use them with microsoft word). This time no luck, they are still uninstalled from my computer.

Any ideas?

This post describes perfectly my problem: http://www.dev-metal.com/fix-ugly-font-rendering-google-chrome/

The only issue is that the article claims the problem is gone! But mine just arrived, pretty much the same day. I cannot confirm the exact day I received the problem because I was traveling :(

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable DirectWrite in Google Chrome 37?](http://superuser.com/questions/803637/how-to-disable-directwrite-in-google-chrome-37)

Comment: Would be a duplicate except that I believe I want DirectWrite activated, it is a good feature. I also want my fonts to render correctly. Also I tried disabling it to troubleshoot and DirectWrite is not the problem.

Answer (score 8):

Ok found the answer and its a lot simpler than you would think. You need to go to:

Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Display -> Adjust ClearType text -> Enable

You will then calibrate your screen and restart chrome and everything will be better! I must have had this enabled and maybe a windows update or graphics card update changed my settings. Good luck to any others who have this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Since Chrome vs 52 Google uses DirectWrite exclusively for font rendering on Windows, which may create font rendering issues for some of you. This is how you can fix the problem with the font display in Chrome: http://www.joe0.com/2016/10/03/fix-bad-fonts-in-chrome/

Comment: I switched the flag from Default to Enable and it definitely fixed the issue in Chrome 54.0.2840.99

Answer (score 3):

I've fixed this by switching `Accelerated 2D canvas` to `disabled` in [chrome://flags](http://chrome://flags) in case of Windows Server 2012 R2 OS.

Comment: this immediately fixed it for me on Windows Server 2016 over an RDP connection.

Comment: This was the only fix that worked when using RDP between two Windows 10 computers.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by installing this free extension:

**Crome Font Super Enhancer**
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-font-super-enhance/ombebcdhklmmkcddekoplmobafpkolmd