# Blurry font on laptop, Windows 7, using the recommended resolution and an updated driver

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, fonts

I have recently replaced my hard drive, and I am going through the process of reinstalling my drivers.

My laptop used to show crisp letters, but now I feel they are slightly blurred!

So I updated my video card driver to the latest version, and double checked with [Device Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Manager) to make sure. It says: NVIDIA GeForce 315M 9.18.13.4144.

But the letters are still blurry...

DirectWrite is disabled, [ClearType](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClearType) helps (the below screenshot is with it), but it doesn't make it go away totally. Without ClearType it is much more noticeably blurry.

I am using the recommended resolution - 1366x768.

Brand and model of my computer is: Toshiba Satellite C660-L20

Here is the image:

[image]

What should I do from here?

Comment: [Sounds like you should disable directwrite in chrome](http://superuser.com/questions/803637/how-to-disable-directwrite-in-google-chrome-37)

Comment: Hello, thank you all for your replies.
Direct text is disabled and cleartype helped a little but it didn't fix it completely. Trying to post the picture now but it says I need 10 reptuation. (Still trying, pardon my noob-ness!)
Resolution is 1366x768
Brand and model of my computer is:
Toshiba Satellite C660-L20

Comment: You mentioned that you are running at the recommended resolution.  Do you know if you were running at that resolution previously?  In some situations, the wrong resolution may look clearer for some people.

Comment: Hi GuitarPicker, thanks for answering. I was using this resolution. There is a resolution that makes the bluriness go away, but it reduces my screen size, and I end up with two black bars of nothingness on the left and right of the actual screen with the letters and all.

Answer (score 2):

The text in your screenshot appears normal to me.

Did you have Windows 7 on your laptop before your HDD upgrade?

I suspect the blurriness you notice is from the subpixel rendering via Microsoft ClearType.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClearType#ClearType.2C_human_vision_and_cognition
http://noel.prodigitalsoftware.com/ForumPosts/Noel_ClearType.jpg

Your screenshot appears to have ClearType enabled.

Try disabling it in Control Panel, Display, Adjust ClearType Text (just uncheck "Turn on ClearType").  Toggle it while looking at the time in the System Tray.  For the change to take effect in Chrome, you have to close all windows and reopen.

Comment: Hi!
Yes I had windows 7 before.
Yes, maybe it is my imagination, or perhaps it is the picture that got a little different when uploading. But I am looking at it right now and can swear it is a little blurry!
At least some parts of it, especially the tabs in chrome and the windows  taskbar (I think that's the name of it)

Comment: I still suspect the blurriness is ClearType.  See my edited answer.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Yes, you are correct that I have ClearType on. I maybe should have posted a screenshot without it? ClearType helps the bluriness but does not make it go away 100%. I have tried to disable ClearType now and it is much worse now. :(